# Mesh distorted when moved away from armature

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, rigify

I'm doing an animation where I have various outfits appear on the character throughout. So I was planning to keyframe each outfit come on and off-screen throughout. When I try to move an outfit off-screen which has the armature applied to it, it does a crazy distortion to it and scales it up. How do i get the mesh to not do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This sounds normal. The mesh is still trying to deform to the armature, but from a distance. Since the deform origins are still about the bones’ heads, the deforms end up having a much greater effect when the mesh is far away from them.

If the clothing just needs to disappear, you can keyframe its render visibility, or animate it’s material so that it becomes transparent over time. If you actually want it to move off of the character, you might try a displacement modifier after the armature one. It feels a bit hackish, but I think it would work.

Comment: I have several outfits so the transparency thing will get messy visual.

What do you mean when you say the displacement modifier hack? I'm all about the fun work around hacks!!!

Comment: @SteveCady Since the deformation is happening from a modifier, you need to move it after that modifier has worked, i.e. another modifier. The first one I thought of that might be able to just plain move the mesh is the displacement modifier. However, I think the transparency or hidden in render system might work better than you think it will. You’ll have to select the objects in the outliner since they will be overlapping of course, but that’s not particularly tricky.

Comment: Appreciate the thoughts. I just have so many outfits the character is going to be wearing that have like 8 outfits overlapped on the viewport will get very crazy, hence why I'm trying to move them off-screen when not being used.

Comment: @SteveCady Fair. However, you can animate the viewport visibility as well, and even connect it with a driver to the render visibility.

Comment: ok doing the alpha thing but now it's doing this.... Made a new post for the issue. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264914/weird-black-artifacts-on-material-alphas